# How to configure Qt to build all modules?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, gcc5

I am following the guide to build Qt from sources, but the build seems to be incomplete, I am building with the following configuration:

> configure -prefix E:\Qt57b_static_mingw5_64 -release -developer-build
>   -opensource -c++std c++1z -static -no-accessibility -platform win32-g++ -qt-zlib -qt-libpng -qt-libjpeg -qt-freetype
>   -no-compile-examples -no-icu -opengl desktop -skip qtscript -nomake examples -nomake tests

Then `jom -j 16` and 15 minutes later it is "done".

I also notice that it doesn't install anything in the prefix directory, and from the timestamps it appears the build has not touched most of the model folders. It only builds qtbase and a few other smaller modules, they do contain the static libs, but the rest is not being built.

Is there something special I need to do in order to build everything? It wasn't the case last time I built Qt. Or maybe something with the configuration is wrong? Or maybe GCC5 has a problem with Qt? Before I was always building with 4.9. Also I am building a beta release.

The platform is win 7 x64, mingw-w64-i686-gcc 5.3.0-1

EDIT: After running a shadow build, I noticed that the configuration indeed only prepares `qtbase` for building, the rest is not built.

Answer (score 0):

You've built likely everything, but you've installed nothing.

You need to:

```
jom -j
jom install -j
```

The number of threads to run in parallel is not needed unless you want to use a number other than the number of logical cores.

Comment: You mean `jom install` right? But even then, I don't see most of the libs, the lib folder is a mere 63 MB. Seems like only qtcore, xmlpatters, gui, network, sql have been built.

Comment: Yes, my suspicions are confirmed, doing a shadow build, in the build directory I see the configuration only prepares qtbase for building.

Comment: @IvanB That's very weird, since I never build Qt in-source, always use a separate build and install folders, and it has always worked with Qt 5. Can you try a with 5.6.1 with same toolset? Also, your `configure` call misses the path to the sources, so perhaps you could amend the question to make it clear.

Comment: I don't think the path to the sources is needed - it is where `configure.bat` is. I may try building it through MSYS later. I've built several Qt versions and the build always included all the modules, this is a first one for me.

Comment: @IvanB Yes, but you are not running configure from that path. So you'll literally type something like `c:\qt\qt-everywhere-5.6.1-src\configure ...` not just `configure ...`

Comment: Tried building the latest snapshot, this time used make instead of jom... it still builds only a few modules - qtbase, qtandroidextras, qtmacextras, qtx11extras, qtactiveqt, qtserialport, qtimageformats, qtsvg and qtxmlpatters. I build the rest manually, but then the install procedure fails...

Comment: As I've said, have you tried an actual release version, not a snapshot, alpha, etc? And have you tried with a known good toolset? Try 5.6.1+VS2015. It should work, because it works for most everyone else. Then switch to your toolset and try again with 5.6.1. If that doesn't work, then clearly the toolset+Qt don't play ball somehow and it can be further investigated. Otherwise it's hard to figure out who did what wrong and where.

Comment: Furthermore, `jom` and [gnu] `make` are not interchangeable. Did you mean `nmake`? I doubt very much that this is supposed to work at all.  `jom`/`nmake` are generally used for Visual Studio compilers. If you're using gcc or clang, you're supposed to configure for gnu makefiles, and use gnu make. The platform mkspecs reflect that I think.